# How to use the GitHub Commits API to list the commits (shas) of a deleted branch?

Tags: rest, github-api

I'm trying to get a list of all the commit shas between 2 dates that belonged to a branch of a particular repo that was deleted. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-commits does not talk about deleted branches. A different API that I can use that wouldn't restore the branch in the process would also be useful to me

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can also supply the sha instead of the deleted branch name as the "sha" query parameter to the Commits API.